# Why does AES decryption have one less round than AES encryption?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm doing some work on AES and I have been seeing lots of pseudocode where, for example, if encryption is done in 10 rounds, decryption is done in 9. Primarily this one, to be exact:

http://people.eku.edu/styere/Encrypt/JS-AES.html

Is this normal? Is there something I'm missing? Is it actually 10 rounds of decryption but I'm reading the code wrong?

Comment: Probably best asked in [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com), this area is about coding.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real question is why people trust these sites publishing some crappy JavaScript version of a cipher.

This is the official NIST pseudo code from [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf):

```
Cipher(byte in[4*Nb], byte out[4*Nb], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)])
begin
    byte state[4,Nb]
    state = in
    AddRoundKey(state, w[0, Nb-1])
    for round = 1 step 1 to Nr–1
        SubBytes(state)
        ShiftRows(state)
        MixColumns(state)
        AddRoundKey(state, w[round*Nb, (round+1)*Nb-1]) end for
    SubBytes(state)
    ShiftRows(state)
    AddRoundKey(state, w[Nr*Nb, (Nr+1)*Nb-1])
    out = state
end

InvCipher(byte in[4*Nb], byte out[4*Nb], word w[Nb*(Nr+1)])
begin
    byte state[4,Nb]
    state = in
    AddRoundKey(state, w[Nr*Nb, (Nr+1)*Nb-1])
    for round = Nr-1 step -1 downto 1
        InvShiftRows(state)
        InvSubBytes(state)
        AddRoundKey(state, w[round*Nb, (round+1)*Nb-1])
        InvMixColumns(state) end for
    InvShiftRows(state)
    InvSubBytes(state)
    AddRoundKey(state, w[0, Nb-1])
    out = state 
end
```

And bang, gone is the difference. The site you pointed to made a mistake, [taking it up to 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven) in the encryption routine.

When looking for code, test vectors *use the original or original documents and specifications*.

Comment: Thanks! And also thanks for the tip!!
I was just worried if there was some hidden detail in AES that made the pseudocode correct or something, hahaha.

Thanks again!